# Adding power components in frequency spectrum

Tags: power

I was doing some problems and I just had some doubts regarding adding up powers in the frequency spectrum.

Let's say I am designing a track and hold system for an ADC and I have a requirement of a 60dB signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). Let's say the input signal is at 0dBm.

Now let's say our clock jitter gives a noise component at -65dBm and we are asked to find smallest capacitor (giving thermal noise) that will allow us to achieve a 60dB SNR.

So my question is, do I now assume that my thermal noise can contribute 5dBm of noise so that when I add it with the jitter power (of -65dBm), I get a total of -65 + 5 = -60dBm? If so, then my capacitor will be extremely small (5dBm = kT/C)?

I feel like that's very incorrect because now my dominant noise component will be at 5dBm.

My question is, how do you guys think about this? How do you add the powers up?

Comment: Caps don’t make thermal noise.

Comment: The track and hold circuit also includes a switch resistance. The combination of the two does produce thermal noise.

Comment: Whether or not it's the resistor or capacitor in the combination that actually produces the noise is irrelvant. Brownian Motion..

Answer (score 0):

Adding 5 dBm of noise would give you 5 dBm of noise.

What I think you want to ask is, what value of noise, added to -65 dBm of translated jitter error, would sum to -60 dBm. The exact value depends on the noise AND JITTER statistics.

If you assumed noise at -65dBm was completely decorrelated from -65 dBm jitter, then their sum would be 3dB greater, or -62dBm. (rms sum of the two amplitudes)

If you assumed complete correlation (highly unlikely!) then their sum would be 6dB greater or -59 dBm, failing to meet the spec.

Therefore the correct answer will be in the region of -65dBm (within a few dB) and I would use that as a reasonable starting point. Go ahead and compute the RMS difference between -60dBm and -65 dBm if you need a more accurate answer to get the last few dB if you need to.

Comment: Hmm. I see. So let's say we aren't talking about noise. And I have some pure sinusoid signal at -30dBm at 2MHz and I also have another pure sinusoid signal of -7dBm also at 2MHz. Now, when I look at my FFT, do I now see -7dBm at 2MHz? Or?

Comment: Are they perfectly correlated? (in phase) If so, 1 uW + 446.6 uW = 447.6 uW. Otherwise, sqrt((1 uW)^2 + (446.6 uW)^2) = ... not much different from 446.6 uW. But that seems to be a completely unrelated question.

Comment: Yes. they are. I understand your calculation in uW. But if I deal in dBm and I add the two components, I get -30dBm-7dBm = -37dBm which is smaller than the 1uW. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mixing log and linear domains. Addition in the log domain is multiplication.